# How to use setter for field in Golang

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm using Gorm to define my models and connect to the database. I have a user type like this

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Email    string `gorm:"unique"`
    Password string
    Language *string
}
```

Is there a way to use a setter for my fields? What I want to achieve is to hash the password before saving it to the database (I already have the function to do that) and prevent a password from being set like this

```
user.Password = "non hashed"
```

**Edit based on @JonathanHall comment:**

I figured out how to create a setter, but I'm not sure if I'm using the correct hook. Is BeforeCreate the right one or is better BeforeSave? If a users update their password (from an interface) does the setter still work?

```
func (u *User) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    password, err := utils.HashPassword(u.Password)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    u.Password = password
    return nil

}
```

Comment: Just create a setter, then.  What have you tried? What problems did you run into?

Comment: You may want to consider getting rid of the `Password` property entirely in favour of a `PasswordHash` property. The password itself isn't something you actually know, and all processes that touch it resolve around hashing some user input and comparing (during login) or storing (during password change) it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom type and implement these two function for it so in case of reading value by sql library `Value()` method and in case of scanning a value from query to your field `Scan()` method is going to be called.

```
Scan(value any) error
Value() (driver.Value, error)
```

for example:

```
type CustomPasswordField string

func (c *CustomPasswordField) Scan(value any) error {
    // Do your scan
    return nil
}

func (c *CustomPasswordField) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    // return the value that you like to store in db
    // for example the hash of the password
    return "", nil
}
```